# Error while compiling SVGA source

Tags: c, linux, vga

I am trying to compile SVGA source to build for shared-library object.
while compiling i am getting this error

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/utils'
gcc -I../include -I. -MM ../utils/restorefont.c ../utils/convfont.c ../utils/restoretextmode.c ../utils/restorepalette.c ../utils/dumpreg.c >.depend
cc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -fno-strength-reduce -pipe -I../include -L../sharedlib -c -o restorefont.o restorefont.c
cc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -fno-strength-reduce -pipe -I../include -L../sharedlib -s -o restorefont restorefont.o -lvga -lm
chmod 4755 restorefont
cc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -fno-strength-reduce -pipe -I../include -L../sharedlib -c -o convfont.o convfont.c
cc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -fno-strength-reduce -pipe -I../include -L../sharedlib -s -o convfont convfont.o -lvga -lm
cc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -fno-strength-reduce -pipe -I../include -L../sharedlib -c -o restoretextmode.o restoretextmode.c
cc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -fno-strength-reduce -pipe -I../include -L../sharedlib -s -o restoretextmode restoretextmode.o -lvga -lm
chmod 4755 restoretextmode
cc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -fno-strength-reduce -pipe -I../include -L../sharedlib -c -o restorepalette.o restorepalette.c
cc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -fno-strength-reduce -pipe -I../include -L../sharedlib -s -o restorepalette restorepalette.o -lvga -lm
chmod 4755 restorepalette
cc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -fno-strength-reduce -pipe -I../include -L../sharedlib -c -o dumpreg.o dumpreg.c
cc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -fno-strength-reduce -pipe -I../include -L../sharedlib -s -o dumpreg dumpreg.o -lvga -lm
chmod 4755 dumpreg
cc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -fno-strength-reduce -pipe -I../include -L../sharedlib -s -o gtfcalc -DTESTING_GTF gtf/gtfcalc.c -lvga -lm
gtf/gtfcalc.c:67: error: static declaration of ‘round’ follows non-static declaration
make[1]: *** [gtfcalc] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/utils'
make: *** [textutils] Error 2
```

Edit::Yes the patch works..But the compilation encounters the next error while compiling the svga_helper.ko module

```
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:1:26: error: linux/config.h: No such file or directory
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:20:35: error: linux/devfs_fs_kernel.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:42:
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/kernel26compat.h: In function ‘devfs_unregister_chrdev’:
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/kernel26compat.h:80: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c: In function ‘svgalib_helper_ioctl’:
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:237: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:242: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:247: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:252: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:258: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:264: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:358: error: ‘SA_SHIRQ’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:358: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:358: error: for each function it appears in.)
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:358: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘request_irq’ from incompatible pointer type
include/linux/interrupt.h:123: note: expected ‘irq_handler_t’ but argument is of type ‘enum irqreturn_t (*)(int,  void *, struct pt_regs *)’
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c: In function ‘svgalib_helper_open’:
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:446: error: ‘SA_SHIRQ’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:446: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘request_irq’ from incompatible pointer type
include/linux/interrupt.h:123: note: expected ‘irq_handler_t’ but argument is of type ‘enum irqreturn_t (*)(int,  void *, struct pt_regs *)’
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c: In function ‘init_module’:
/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.c:651: error: implicit declaration of function ‘class_device_create’
make[3]: *** [/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper/main.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.0.1.el6.x86_64'
make[1]: *** [default] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/manmatha/Downloads/svgalib-1.9.25/kernel/svgalib_helper'
make: *** [installmodule] Error 2
```

Comment: What version of `gcc` are you using? Recent versions (e.g. 4.8) give both conflicting declarations in their error messages, so correcting the problem should be easy. Why don't you install the `libsvga1-dev` package from your distribution?

Comment: I am using gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) 
on RHEL6

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to go for a newer version of svgalib. 1.4.3 is pretty old and no longer maintained. If I remember correctly it needed to be patched to work with newer compilers as well.
Try one of the 1.9.x versions from http://svgalib.org/

For later versions, if you get the error:

```
error: static declaration of 'round' follows non-static declaration
```

Apply the following patch:

```
--- svgalib-1.9.25/utils/gtf/gtfcalc.c
+++ svgalib-1.9.25/utils/gtf/gtfcalc.c
@@ -68,5 +68,5 @@

-static double round(double v) 
+double round(double v) 
 { 
    return floor(v + 0.5); 
 }
```

EDIT:

With your latest compile issue in the svga_helper.ko module, set the NO_HELPER variable to disable building svga_helper.ko. config.h etc. were removed form more recent kernels. From the Readme:

> There is a compile time option to return to old behaviour, of using
>   root privileges to access /dev/mem, instead of svgalib helper. To
>   compile for this select the NO_HELPER option in Makefile.cfg.

Comment: Yes...i have downloaded SVGALIB 1.9.25 and tried to make install that..But still getting error..I have edited my question according to the situation

Comment: Edited the answer, see patch.

Comment: By the way, you should have left the original question in place and just updated. Right now it might be confusing for others since the first part of my answer isn't connected to your question anymore.

Comment: I would declare and define instead `static inline double round (double v)`

Comment: Your latest error is related to newer kernels, see my updated answer.